# How to generate the first 200 samples from MNIST?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, sample, mnist, torchvision

I have tried to take only the 200 first samples from MNIST using pytorch.
And how to generateonly 3 and 8 samples from MNIST
Someone can help me get them?

I tried:

```
def get_data(batch_size = 100):
  transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
  all_train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `torch.utils.data.Subset`:

```py
from torch.utils.data import Subset
data = Subset(all_train_dataset, range(200))
```

This way you will get out a `torch.utils.data.Dataset` that can passed onto a `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`.